# How do i launch firefox on android device using adb?

Tags: android, firefox, adb

how do i launch firefox using adb. For chrome it works if i use-

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main
```

Answer (score 3):

You can open Firefox using:

```
adb shell am start -n org.mozilla.firefox/org.mozilla.gecko.BrowserApp
```

The general command is `adb shell am start -n package/activity`

To find this information, open the app and run `adb shell dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp'`

The output will something like this

```
mCurrentFocus=Window{129432bd0 u0 org.mozilla.firefox/org.mozilla.gecko.BrowserApp}


mFocusedApp=AppWindowToken{f7cdbbd token=Token{805d714 ActivityRecord{8a8dd67d0 u0 org.mozilla.firefox/org.mozilla.gecko.BrowserApp t9631}}}
```

You can find the `package/activity` you need to launch the app from this output.